# How to "change" single values in large objects in elegant way?

Tags: haskell

For example, i have

```
data ShipDesign = ShipDesign {
      offense :: Offense
    , defense :: Defense
    , maxHealth :: Integer
    , repairRate :: Integer
    , stealth :: Integer
    , radar :: Integer
    , speed :: Integer
    , shipType :: String
    ...
    }
```

Now i want to change the defense.
The known way to do this is:

```
changeDefense :: (Defense -> Defense) -> ShipDesign -> ShipDesign
changeDefense fDef sd@(ShipDesign o d m rr s r sp st ...) = ShipDesign o (fDef d) m rr s r sp st ...
```

which isn't elegant. Especially in games its common to change just a few values per step.

My Question is: is there a library, design pattern or other way to change a single value in a more elegant manner?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, you can use *record update notation:*

```
 changeDefense :: (Defense -> Defense) -> ShipDesign -> ShipDesign
 changeDefense fDef sd = sd { defense = fDef (defense sd) }
```

As you work with it, though, the limitations of record update notation will show themselves, and you will want something more powerful.  At that point, you should start to learn about [lenses](http://newartisans.com/2012/11/getting-started-with-lenses/).

Comment: An alternative is to just jump into lenses directly, since they (at least in my opinion) provide a much more functional soludion to the problem than special syntax does.

Answer (score 3):

I wonder why nobody proposed lens(es)?

I recommend this short introduction by Gabriel Gonzalez:
http://www.haskellforall.com/2013/05/program-imperatively-using-haskell.html?m=1

Edit: oh ... I over read the last sentence. But the suggestion still stands.